# How to find two consecutive positive-negative values in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sign

I have the following array:

```
X
array([ 3.5, -3, 5.4, 3.7, 14.9, -7.8, -3.5, 2.1])
```

For each values of `X`  I know its recording time `T`. I want to find the indexes between two consecutive positive-negative or viceversa. Concluding I would like an array like

```
Y = array([ T(1)-T(0), T(2)-T(1),  T(5)-T(4), T(7)-T(6)])
```

Comment: There isn't anything between consecutive elements.  I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Take them pairwise, then filter XOR on sign.

Comment: So far I tried `tmp = np.sign(x[0])
l = list()
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    if (np.sign(x[i]) + tmp)==0:
        tmp = np.sign(x[i])
        deltat = T[i]-T[i-1]
        l.append(deltat / np.timedelta64(1, 's'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps iterating over the array in a list comprehension would work for you:

```
In [35]: x=np.array([ 3.5, -3, 5.4, 3.7, 14.9, -7.8, -3.5, 2.1])

In [36]: y=np.array([b-a for a,b in zip(x, x[1:]) if (a<0) != (b<0)])

In [37]: y
Out[37]: array([ -6.5,   8.4, -22.7,   5.6])
```

### Edit

I apparently didn't understand the question completely. Try this instead:

```
In [38]: X=np.array([ 3.5, -3, 5.4, 3.7, 14.9, -7.8, -3.5, 2.1])

In [39]: T=np.array([ 0, 0.1, 2, 3.5, 5, 22, 25, 50])

In [40]: y=np.array([t1-t0 for x0,x1,t0,t1 in zip(X, X[1:], T, T[1:]) if (x0<0) != (x1<0)])

In [41]: y
Out[41]: array([  0.1,   1.9,  17. ,  25. ])
```

Comment: Great: however the time is stored in another array. How can I do that difference of the corresponding time in the other array?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. Correct answer coming right up.